# Matplotlib - Increase height of box containing a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I increase the height of the box containing a plot? I would like to enlarge the font of the legend and have it fit inside the box. I currently have to use the yticks to increase the height but would like the "1.2" in the plot below to not be shown. I hope it is clear.

```
e3dssim = [0.879, 0.810, 0.798]
v3dssim = [0.866, 0.852, 0.846]
ssim = e3dssim+v3dssim
e3dpsnr = [29.31, 27.24, 26.82]
v3dpsnr = [28.31, 27.89, 27.66]
psnr = e3dpsnr+v3dpsnr
T = [r'$x_{1:10}\rightarrow \hat{x}_{11:30}$',r'$x_{1:10}\rightarrow \hat{x}_{11:50}$',r'$x_{1:10}\rightarrow \hat{x}_{11:70}$']*2
Method = ["E3D"]*len(e3dssim)+["Ours"]*len(v3dssim)
df = pd.DataFrame({"SSIM": ssim, "PSNR": psnr, "T":T, "":Method})

labelsize=20
ticksize=20
f,ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(10,10))
sns.barplot(x="T", y="SSIM", hue="", data=df, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].tick_params(labelsize=ticksize)
ax[0].set_yticks([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.2])
ax[0].set_xlabel(xlabel="",fontsize=labelsize)
ax[0].set_ylabel(ylabel="SSIM",fontsize=labelsize)
sns.barplot(x="T", y="PSNR", hue="", data=df, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].tick_params(labelsize=ticksize)
ax[1].set_xlabel(xlabel="",fontsize=labelsize)
ax[1].set_ylabel(ylabel="PSNR",fontsize=labelsize)

ax[0].legend(fontsize=15)
ax[1].get_legend().remove()

#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
#plt.savefig("kth.png")
```

[image]

EDIT:

I set the yticks to go to 0.8 but the ylim to 1.2 and I am able to achieve what I want.

```
ax[0].set_yticks([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8])
ax[0].set_ylim([0.2,1.2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
plt.tight_layout()
```

here, put the width and height you want.
tight layout is just for arranging them properly